# How to capitalize names

Tags: c#, .net

Basically if I want to transform a name from

```
stephen smith
```

to

```
Stephen Smith
```

I can easily do it with come CSS on the page, but ideally I would like to catch it earlier on and change it when it comes out of the database. How can I get C# to capitalise a string?

Is there a function for this?

Comment: +1 for your question because the replies shows that "beautiful" and "correct" aren't the domains of computers :-) Beautiness (and correctness) is in the eye of the beholder! :-)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You can do this using the `ToTitleCase` method of the [System.Globalization.TextInfo](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312890) class:

```
CultureInfo cultureInfo = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

Console.WriteLine(textInfo.ToTitleCase(title));
Console.WriteLine(textInfo.ToLower(title));
Console.WriteLine(textInfo.ToUpper(title));
```

Comment: It's VERY important to read the description of ToTileCase (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx ) before using it. I think it isn't very "good". Its behaviour isn't even defined (it's something like "it does as it does".) The note is fantastic: "We reserve the right to make this API slower in the future."

Comment: -1, sorry, but `ToTitleCase` is for normalization of casing in *titles* — like titles of news articles — but not for human names. Thus in respect to the actual culture you may end-up with an unwanted result.

Comment: I think with any *automatic* string formatting method, there will be edge cases where the value that is produced is not 100% as expected, i.e. with surnames like `d'Ythaq`. However, this is definitely the best method currently available in the .Net Framework for casing people's names, short of writing one yourself which *does* handle the edge cases.

Comment: @Dexter You are wrong. Title case has nothing to do with *human names*.

Comment: For a programmer there isn't any difference between the name of a person and the title of a book! (citation: Xanatos, 20 Feb 2010) :-) :-)

Comment: Sorry @Ondrej, but if I'm wrong then Microsoft are too - the title of the KB article I linked is `How to convert strings to ...  title (proper) case` - i.e. Microsoft consider this to be a suitable method of casing Proper names. They do identify some edge cases where this method does not work, but even so I stand by my assertion that "this is the best method currently available *in the .Net Framework* for casing people's names"

Comment: @Dexter Studied the documentation again, reflectored the method and tried it with various cultures. I actually didn't expect it to behave the same practically across all cultures — I think the current implementation in .NET is inadequate. Forexample, title-case in Czech means uppercasing the first letter of the first word *only*. However, I'd still avoid using it because it may change significantly in the future.

Comment: Wiki says that some people choose not to capitalise their names at all (I didn't realise I could opt out), and in some cultures it's normal for names contain "the", which presumably wouldn't be capitalised by title casing rules. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capitalization#Nouns)

Comment: This method is very well hidden. Why is it not a member of `System.String` like `ToUpper` or `ToUpperInvariant`?

Comment: I'm glad Microsoft decided to implement an incorrect and potentially unstable method as opposed to something more useful like String.Capitalize

Answer (score 30):

Names are tricky. The simple rules of First Letters **do not apply**. The only sensible approach here is to *ask your users* how they want it. Anything else can cause offence.

If my name is MacPhearson, ODowel, or just simply marc, Marc or even mArC - then frankly: leave it alone. Trust the user to get it right. This gets even more tricky as you go between cultures.

Comment: Only one comment: unless the user is the "owner" of the name, the user is probably the worst person whom to ask. And even if it's the owner, it's only fifty fifty. Teh (written as teh) sms generation is quite prone on ignoring "correct" case rules.

Comment: well its more of a admin thing that it is users. The names are names of boxers who we have on the website and is not nothing our users are typing in!

Comment: @Steve aren't the administrators users of your system?

Comment: @Steve as Marc hints at you will have problems with a lot of british/scottish/Irish names where not only the first letter is capitalized. Other languages might have similar oddities compared to title casing

Answer (score 11):

This is an extension method on the string class that capitalizes a single word. You can use it alongside a `str.Split()` and `str.Join` to capitalize every word of the `str` string. You can add checks for empty or one character length strings.

```
public static string Capitalize(this string word)
{
    return word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + word.Substring(1).ToLower();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that the process will most likely be slow if you have many, many strings to change case...

```
string str = "to title case";
Char[] ca = str.ToCharArray();

foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(str, @"\b[a-z]"))
{
    ca[m.Index] = Char.ToUpper(ca[m.Index]);
}
Console.WriteLine(new string(ca));
```

Or you could also use a custom evaluator to change the case like this:

```
string str = "to title case";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(str, @"\b[a-z]", delegate (Match m)
                                              {
                                                  return m.Value.ToUpper();
                                              }
                  ));
```

**Note** that in my test with 1,000,000 iterations the first method was only 0.48 seconds faster than the one with the evaluator (the first one took 6.88 seconds and the latter 7.36 seconds to complete the 1,000,000 iterations) so I wouldn't take speed into account to choose either...

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. Providing you know the string you are handling is a name (or, better to say, a sequence of human names separated by spaces) you should be able to code it yourself within one `for` cycle and using [`Char.ToUpper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f85c1b1.aspx). However, there a culture-specific cases like Arabian words "bin", "al", etc. used in names, which shall not be capitalized (providing a Latin transcription is used). The same holds for "von" or "van" in Western languages.

Please note that the [`TextInfo.ToTitleCase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) **serves a different purpose** — it's not intended to capitalize first letters of human names, but to provide proper casing of *titles* (like headlines of news articles to be clear).

Although the current implementation in .NET can easily serve the requested purpose, I'd avoid doing so. The reason is the implementation may change significantly in the future and hence it's safer to make a custom implementation for human names. Moreover, I doubt the method is really usable for title-casing of strings with respect to the given culture. For example, in [Czech](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Czech#Proper_noun) (`"cs-CZ"`) the proper title-case should capitalize just the first letter of the first word *only*.

Answer (score 2):

A slight extension on the answer offered by Pedro:

```
Regex.Replace(Name, @"(?:(M|m)(c)|(\b))([a-z])", delegate(Match m) {
    return String.Concat(m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper(), m.Groups[2].Value, m.Groups[3].Value, m.Groups[4].Value.ToUpper());
 });
```

This will correctly capitalize McNames in addition to title case. For example,

```
"simon mcguinnis" → "Simon McGuinnis"
```

- The first non-capture group will match any word-break character OR "Mc" / "mc".
- If it matches a word-break, then groups 1 and 2 are empty and group 3 contains that character.
- If it matches "Mc" or "mc" the groups 1 and 2 contain "m" and "c" and group 3 is empty.
- Group 1 (the "m" or "M") is capitalized.
- Group 2 (the "c") remains un-altered.
- Group 3 (the break character) remains un-altered.
- Group 4 (the first letter of the next word) is capitalized.

All four groups, empty or otherwise, are concatenated to generate the return string.

Answer (score 2):

I use a single line:

```
string.Join(" ", str.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(c => c.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + c.Substring(1).ToLower()));
```

Comment: An explanation would in order. E.g., what is the gist/idea and how is it different from previous answers? Please respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57463038/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with surnames that have a ' character in them.

```
        if (Surname.Contains("'"))
        {
           String[] Names = Surname.Split('\'').ToArray();
           Surname = textInfo.ToTitleCase(Names[0].ToString());
           Surname += "''";
           Surname += textInfo.ToTitleCase(Names[1].ToString());
        }
```