# How to retrive values, First letter capital from database table using LINQ Query?

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Capitalize names using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057793/how-to-capitalize-names-using-c-sharp)

How can i retrieve values from database tables in First letter capital format?

My LINQ Query is like this,

```
            DBEntities Context = new DBEntities ();    
            var UserNameEntity = (from a in Context.UserInformation
                                  where a.UserId == UserId
                                  select a).First();
            string UserName = UserNameEntity.FirstName + " " + UserNameEntity.LastName;   

            return UserName;
```

I am getting user name : bhargav soni

but i want this should be like Bhargav Soni

How can i do that?

Comment: provide right tag to your question.. it does not belong to LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `FirstName` and `LastName` properties, use the indexer to retrieve the first character, and call the `Substring()` method to retrieve the rest of the string.

```
DBEntities Context = new DBEntities ();  
var UserNameEntity = (from a in Context.UserInformation
                     where a.UserId == UserId
                     select a).First();
string UserName = char.ToUpper(UserNameEntity.FirstName[0])
                  + UserNameEntity.FirstName.Substring(1)
                  + " "
                  + char.ToUpper(UserNameEntity.LastName[0])
                  + UserNameEntity.LastName.Substring(1);

return UserName;
```

This assumes that both properties are at least two characters in length.

You can also do this entirely in LINQ:

```
DBEntities Context = new DBEntities ();  
IEnumerable<string> userNames = from a in Context.UserInformation
                                where a.UserId == UserId
                                let firstName = a.FirstName
                                let lastName = a.LastName
                                select (char.ToUpper(firstName[0])
                                    + firstName.Substring(1)
                                    + " "
                                    + char.ToUpper(lastName[0])
                                    + lastName.Substring(1));

return displayNames.First();
```

Obviously, using [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.string.format.aspx) instead of concatenation may or may not improve readability.

Comment: Thanks... I go with your first answer.

Answer (score 2):

This question is not related to LINQ, but a way that you could do this would be

```
TextInfo myTI = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo;

DBEntities Context = new DBEntities ();    
var UserNameEntity = (from a in Context.UserInformation
                     where a.UserId == UserId
                    select a).First();
string UserName = string.Format("{0} {1}", myTI.ToTitleCase(UserNameEntity.FirstName), myTI.ToTitleCase(UserNameEntity.LastName));   

return UserName;
```

Comment: :Thanks.. I tried this as-well..

Answer (score 1):

The `String` class does not include a method that converts a string to title case. The `ToTitleCase` method resides in the TextInfo class, which is a member of the `System.Globalization` namespace. Unlike the `ToUpper` and `ToLower` methods of the String class, the `ToTitleCase` method is not a static method and requires an instance of the class.

```
    CultureInfo cultureInfo   = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
    TextInfo textInfo = cultureInfo.TextInfo;

    DBEntities Context = new DBEntities ();    
                var UserNameEntity = (from a in Context.UserInformation
                                      where a.UserId == UserId
                                      select a).First();
                string UserName = textInfo.ToTitleCase(UserNameEntity.FirstName) + " " + 
textInfo.ToTitleCase(UserNameEntity.LastName);   

                return UserName;
```

Check this for detailed information:
[How to convert strings to lower, upper, or title (proper) case by using Visual C#](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312890)

Comment: Thanks. i appreciate your answer and such a nice explanation. Thanks again..